# Eclipse BIRT create a Custom Emitter as class

Tags: java, birt

I am trying to create a custom Emitter for BIRT. I created a Plugin, here works everything fine the problem is that I need it as a Java class.
The problem is when I try to Render in my own Emitter it says that the custom RenderOption is not supported.

Here is some of my Code:

IJsonRenderOption:

```
package org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.json;

import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IRenderOption;

public interface IJsonRenderOption extends IRenderOption {
    public static final String OUTPUT_FORMAT_JSON = "json";
    public static final String OUTPUT_EMITTERID_JSON = "org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.json";
}
```

JsonRenderOption:

```
package org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.json;

import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IRenderOption;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.RenderOption;

public class JsonRenderOption extends RenderOption implements IJsonRenderOption {    
    public JsonRenderOption() {
        super();
    }

    public JsonRenderOption(IRenderOption options) {
        super(options);
    }
}
```

I hope somebody can help me

Greetz

Answer (score -1):

Try importing the following packages

```
importPackage(org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.json);

importPackage(org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IRenderOption);
importPackage(org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.RenderOption);
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. please add more information when answering a question so that it is easier for the person to understand.